# Firebase Project Initialization Error: Failed to list available Google Cloud Platform projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am trying to set up an Ionic application to use an existing Firebase project and when running `Firebase init` in the windows console I get this message:

`Error: Failed to list available Google Cloud Platform projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.`

The log shows a 401 error accessing the server.

Answer (score 5):

Why this happens is still not entirely clear to me. I used to be able to run this command from the windows console simply by running `firebase login`. But at least I found a workaround to solve the issue.

To fix it:

- run `Firebase login:ci` which will, from the console open a browser window for you to log into the CI - Continuous Integration - server with your Google account
- copy the token that is generated, something like `1//012abc345def...`
- in the console enter: `set FIREBASE_TOKEN=1//012abc345def...`
- you can then run: `firebase init --token "%FIREBASE_TOKEN%"`

The set is necessary to register the token as an environment variable otherwise the process will fail at some point.

The syntax is only slightly different if you are using bash.

Comment: @Buddhi Kavindra: be more precise pls. What does didn't work mean? What error did you get and at which step? I may get back to coding on FB later next month and will double check and update if needed. PM me with more detail if needed and we can work from there. Thx

Comment: find details here : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2469

Comment: Apparently the ticket you link to points out that you can't reach the server because of a firewall configuration issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to

```
firebase logout
firebase login
```

Comment: I upvoted it because it worked for me. However, your point is well-taken that it doesn't explain the solution enough. What happened is that I was already logged into FB, and my OAuth2 credentials timed out. Unfortunately, the `firebase` cmd isn't able to use a refresh token to get a new access token, so you're logged in but in a "zombie state." Logging out clears the expired credentials, and logging in refreshes you with new credentials to continue using FB.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

`firebase login --reauth`